# vue.js, Lazy Loading Routes, chunks error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, lazy-loading

I use Vue Cli

To create a lazy loading components as follows:

```
router/admin/index.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

function lazyLoad(component){
    return() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "/chunk/" */ '../../components/' + component)
}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: Dashboard,
        name: 'dashboard',
        meta: { title: 'Dashboard' },
    },
    {
        path: '/admin/devices',
        component: lazyLoad('Admin/Devices.vue'),
        name: 'devices',
        meta: { title: 'Devices' },
        children: [
            {
                path: ":id",
                component: lazyLoad('Admin/Devices/Device.vue'),
                name: 'device',
                meta: { title: 'Device' },
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

export default router
```

After compilation, files with a name from 0> appear in the "chunk" folder. When accessing the route, a 404 error, because path is not specified correctly:

**/host.com/js/0.js**

And it should:

**/host.ru/public/vue/dist/js/chunk/...**

Question: Where do I need to specify path?

Comment: `webpackChunkName` is a name, not a path, remove the slashes

Comment: webpackChunkName is name and path for chunks! Without /chunk/ it will compile without folder "chunk"

Comment: I found a solution, but it’s not good enough, because now the link has also changed.

In vue.config.js publicPath: '/public/vue/dist',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way:

in the file **vue.config.js** indicated the path to the compiled files

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/public/vue/dist',
}
```

In a file where routes are registered changed

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
```

On

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes
})
```